# is it possible to overlay an image on each frame of a video using FFMPEG

Tags: image, video, ffmpeg, video-watermarking

I am trying to overlay 10 different images on a 10 second video. I am currently able to overlay one image over the entire time span of the video using FFMPEG. I want to be able to see a different image every sec on the video.

How can i achieve this if it is possible?

Regards,
Reuben

Comment: You can, but it's going to be one long command. Are all images the same size and to be at the same position?

Comment: yes. It will be the same size as the video and so will be positioned at the start i.e. 0,0

Comment: @Mulvya what is the command?

Comment: Use the [one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34673360/5726027) by incBrain.

Answer (score 4):

Yes the command should then look similar to this:

```
ffmpeg -y 
  -i foo.mp4 -i foo.jpg -i bar.jpg [...put more pics here...]
  -filter_complex "
      [0:v][1:v] overlay=25:25:enable='between(t,0,1)' [tmp];
      [tmp][2:v] overlay=25:25:enable='between(t,1,2)' [tmp]
      ...continue the same way...
  " 
bar.mp4
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I''d been searching for this solutions for a while... Praise Jesus!!

Answer (score 3):

An easy method assuming you have an ordered sequence of images:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -pattern_type glob -framerate 1 -i "*.png" \
-filter_complex overlay output.mp4
```

The downside is that all input images need to be the same width, height, and pixel format: otherwise the overlaid frames may not display properly.

Comment: how do you mean `ordered sequence of images` ?

Comment: Currently I have 10 images sequentially named from 1..10 but the command did not display the images in that order